# Top-level Akka actor escalation and shutdown hooking

Tags: exception, akka, akka-supervision

In my Akka system there is a top-level ("root") actor, `Initializer`, from which all other actors come from. There is also an actor, `Destroyer`, that is responsible for shutting down the system gracefully when it receives a `Destroy` message. There are several conditions under which an actor would send a `Destroy` to the `Destroyer`, but those don't really matter here.

I would now like to implement functionality in `Initializer`'s `SupervisorStrategy` where, if it can't handle a failure/exception thrown by one of its chidren, it will interpret that as a "stop the world"-type event, and shut the system down gracefully.

My knee jerk reaction is to have `Initializer` escalate the failure, but I'm not sure what happens when the top-most actor escalates. It would be nice if there was a way for that escalation to somehow invoke the `Desroyer`, but not sure how to wire that all up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question here: [How to escalate top-most supervisors in Akka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660970/how-to-escalate-top-most-supervisors-in-akka/31670664#31670664)

Essentially, in your configuration set:

```
akka.actor.guardian-supervisor-strategy = "akka.actor.StoppingSupervisorStrategy"
```

Then in your `Initializer` you should escalate any exceptions which you want to be fatal for the system. The Initializer will then be stopped. You could watch the `Initializer` from the `Destroyer` and react to the `Terminated` event, or if you want to stick to your custom `Destroy` message, send `Destroy` to the `Destroyer` from `postStop()` within the `Initializer`.