# How Akka Futures and Supervisor Strategies deal with failure

Tags: java, exception, callback, akka, akka-supervision

Akka **Java** here. I just read the Akka docs on [the “ask” pattern using futures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137026/4009451) and am not understanding how several things work, with respect to scenarios when *both* supervisor strategies (deciders) and failure callbacks are part of the picture.

#### Parent asking a Child

Say I have two actors, `Fizz` and `Buzz`, where `Fizz` is the parent/creator of `Buzz`. Because `Fizz` is `Buzz`’s parent, it has a `SupervisorStrategy` for `Buzz` that handles its failures:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
class Fizz extends UntypedActor {
    ActorRef buzz

    // Contstructor omitted for brevity, but Buzz is the child of
    // Fizz.

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof FizzRequest) {
            FizzRequest fReq = message as FizzRequest

            // Exceptions thrown here (inside of Buzz) will be
            // handled by Fizz’s supervisor strategy.
            Future<BuzzData> bDataFut = Patterns.ask(buzz,
                fReq.buzzRequest, 500)
            bDataFut.onComplete(new GetBuzzDataCallback())

            // etc.
        } else {
            unhandled(message)
        }
    }

    @Override
    SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy() {
        new FizzSupervisorStrategy()
    }
}

class Buzz extends UntypedActor {
    // …etc.
}

class FizzDecider extends Function<Throwable,Directive> {
    @Override
    Directive apply(Throwable throwable) {
        if(throwable instanceof BuzzIsAngryException) {
            return SupervisorStrategy.restart()
        }

        SupervisorStrategy.stop()
    }
}

class FizzSupervisorStrategy extends OneForOneStrategy {
    FizzSupervisorStrategy() {
        super(true, new FizzDecider())
    }
}

class GetBuzzDataCallback extends OnComplete<BuzzData> {
    @Override
    void onComplete(Throwable failure, BuzzData bData) {
        if(failure != null) {
            // If Buzz is the child of Fizz, does this code execute, or
            // just the FizzDecider above? Or both? I’m so confused!
        } else {
            // Handle success. Likely use an ‘Inbox’ to send
            // ‘bData’ back to Fizz.
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes, `Fizz` needs to ask `Buzz` for some data. When this happens, there can be one of three results:

1. `Buzz` returns successfully and provides the `GetBuzzDataCallback` with `bData`; or
2. `Buzz` throws a `BuzzIsAngryException`; or
3. `Buzz` throws some other kind of exception/error

**I’m wondering what happens with the latter two cases:**

- Who is notified of the exception, in what order, and how? In other words, is the `GetBuzzDataCallback` sent the exception as its `Throwable failure` argument? Or, is the `FizzFailureDecider` invoked? Or both (it seems a bit redundant and complicating if *both* the callback and the decider/supervisor strategy are passed the error)?

#### Parent asking a non-Child

Same scenario as above, except now `Fizz` is *not* the parent/creator of `Buzz`. In this case, can I just assume that the `GetBuzzDataCallback` is sent the exception (as its `Throwable failure` argument)?

I guess at the root of my question(s) is this: when a supervisor strategy **and** a future callback are involved, who gets notified when a child exception is thrown, and in what order? As I mentioned above, to me it would be extra confusing if both receive the failure/exception because then you might have a supervisor strategy trying to restart a `Buzz` while the callback is trying to do something else (possibly conflicting) with the exception.

**Please note**: Although certainly not a requirement, I would greatly appreciate it if any code snippets provided be in Java and *not* Scala (Scala looks like hieroglyphics to me)!

Comment: Why the downvote sans explanation (what I call a *hit-and-run*)?!? This question shows research, is not a dupe and is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Unhand me you fiend!

Comment: Your link is to another question you asked, not the Akka docs. (note I didn't downvote you)

Answer (score 0):

What ask does is basically starting a temporary actor that will be the sender of the message so that when the recipient replies it will end up in this temporary actor. The temporary actor creates a `Promise` and gives away the `Future` for it to the caller. If a reply arrives before the given timeout, the temporary actor completes the `Promise` with the successful result.

Supervision always happens in actors, and since ask is implemented using an actor, there isn't anything different about the interaction compared to random other actor sending it the message that could make the supervision work differently.

In your case an exception will bubble up to the parent actor, so that it can supervise the child. Then, unless you somehow send a reply message triggered by this failure, the timeout will hit and the temporary `ask`-actor will fail the future with an `AskTimeoutException`.

So, as this failure would reach the parent from two ways, it might not generally be a good idea to use the ask pattern with parent to child communication.